# Kali Linux fresh install. What should I install and why is the application bar missing?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I recently installed Kali Linux on my laptop. It's more like i want to test things, get used of a more difficult environment and do my university projects than already being an advanced programmer.

So what are the first things you suggest to install to make it better? The only things I've already got after a fresh installation is Visual Studio, Open Office and XAMPP. Also, I noticed that other users have a application bar on the left while I don't. How do I add that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should install what you need. We can't guess what you'll be doing with this OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Kali V2020, it defaults to the Xfce interface which is very nice and bears a nice resemblance to Window 10 (at the top instead of bottom).

Click the top left Dragon Icon and take a look. Many of your apps in here.  Click on All Applications and they show up on the right side of this little dialogue box. Everything is there.

For another look, click on the Blue Globe, top right. This also has your applications and Kali tools organized for you. As I have added apps, the app shortcut shows up in both menus. This is automatic and much like Windows 10.

I prefer this desktop and the way it works to Gnome in Ubuntu.

I have both machines (Kali and Ubuntu) here and I am working in Kali as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install different themes from gnome look. There are thousands of themes available.

Default kali uses KDE environment which uses high ram but looks nice.

You want task bar at left . So u would have to install gnome desktop.

Warning.
Kali is not for beginners. Try linux like Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Mint.

Using kali without experience can make you fall in trouble.